# Why is my printf() statement being run twice?

Tags: c, printf

After the initial iteration, the `printf()` output is shown twice each iteration. Why?

```
int main()
{
  int ch;
  for( ch = ' '; ch != 'q'; ) {
     printf("Enter a character: ");
     ch = getchar();
  }
  printf("You entered a q!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

The terminal output is:

```
Enter a character: w
Enter a character: Enter a character: a
Enter a character: Enter a character: q
You entered a q!
```

Comment: What are you typing in as input?

Comment: That's because of newline.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why exactly does a newline cause this behavior?

Comment: @nbro Enter Key is received in `getchar` as a newline.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Of course, I know that, but why is the `printf` function in the loop executed apparently twice?

Comment: @Gilles I retracted my vote to close this question since the other question is asking about what the expected behavior is and how to make it work as the OP wanted. In this case, the OP is also asking why this is happening.

Comment: @nbro `'\n'` is not `'q'` so the loop is continued.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So, essentially, we're seeing twice `Enter a character:` in `Enter a character: Enter a character: a` because `\n` is consumed automatically in the iteration after entering "w" as input and pressing enter. This is exactly what I wanted you to tell me and the others.

Comment: @nbro It is not automatic, because that is how it is done.

Comment: Sidenote: `printf` is a function, not a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone has already stated, `getchar()` is consuming a newline ('\n') making you have two iterations. A way to fix this is to do this:

```
int main(){
  int ch;
  for( ch = ' '; ch != 'q'; ) {
     printf("Enter a character: ");
     ch = getchar();
     getchar();
  }
  printf("You entered a q!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

The reason for the second `getchar()` is to consume that newline so you won't have a double output of the same thing. Using this method will only work if you are only inputting one character.

Comment: That's not a good way to fix it. It only works if the user entered a single character on the line. A better fix would be to loop over `getchar` until a newline is found.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't enter `w` on the command line. You entered `w\n`. That's two characters.

Answer (score 2):

Because `getchar` reads a character and '\n', not only the character that you typed.

Answer (score 0):

As comments and previous answers have stated, `getchar()` does not read the newline at the end. The quick fix is to add another `getchar();` at the end of your loop like this:

```
int main()
{
  int ch;
  for( ch = ' '; ch != 'q'; ) {
     printf("Enter a character: ");
     ch = getchar();
     getchar();
  }
  printf("You entered a q!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

If you want a more flexible solution that will work if the user types more than one character, try this:

```
int main()
{
  int ch;
  for( ch = ' '; ch != 'q'; ) {
     printf("Enter a character: ");
     ch = getfirstchar();
  }
  printf("You entered a q!\n");

  return 0;
}
int getfirstchar() {
  int c = getchar();
  while(getchar() != '\n')
    ;
  return c;
}
```

I moved reading the character into a separate function so it's more adaptable to future code.